# Why i can not to connect sql server with android?

Tags: android

I'm beginner in adnroid studio,i want write simple application to connect sql server and read any table and close connection,i read this tutorial:
[how to connect MS SQL](http://www.parallelcodes.com/connect-android-to-ms-sql-database-2/)

i write step by step up link,but i get this error when fire log in button i get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.nothing.myapplication.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:52)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

in this line:

```
st = connect.createStatement();
```

my connection string in android is this:

```
ConnectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + "192.168.36.171" + ";"
                    + "databaseName=" + "HYPER" + ";user=" + "razzaqi"
                    + ";password=" + "beh1368421" + ";";
```

how can i solve that?thanks.

Comment: You really don't want to connect directly to a database from a user application. Hardcoding user credentials for a database directly in the app is never a good idea. Create an API that you can call via https that handles the database queries.

Comment: are you have any link for another api?thanks my friend

Comment: *are you have any link for another api?* --> [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that

```
connect = ConnectionHelper(username, password, db, ipaddress);
```

returns null.

I have to suggest you to use something like that http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm

Comment: ok,but up paramater is my ip address and another field.

Comment: check this tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm to do something like that